# jQuery nested list from JSON not working. [solved, but comes another]

Tags: jquery, json

I'm creating a nested nested nested list, but I'm having problem assigning my `buffer` inside a UL. 
I tried `$('ul#lists').html(buffer)` but it didn't print out...

**JSON**

```
{
"browse": [
    { 
        "name":"browse by state" , 
        "command":"state" }, 

    { 
        "name":"browse by equipment" , 
        "command":"equipment" }, 

    { 
        "name":"browse by brand" , 
        "command":"brand" }
]
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="browser">
        <ul id="lists"></ul>
</section>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function(tree_click){
    $('ul#lists').on('click','.c',function(){
    var test = "";
    $(this).removeClass('c'); //To assign this event once

    $.get('scripts/list.json', function(result, status){    
        var buffer = "";
        $.each(result, function(i, val){            
            for(var i=0; i < val.length; i++){ 
            var item = val[i];
            buffer+="<li><a href='#' cmd='"+item.command+"'>"+item.name+"</a></li>";} 
        });
        $(e.target).parent().append(buffer);
    });
});
});
```

**The problem is solved. I updated my question with the solution.**

But now my list toggler isn't working.

I use this for the toggler,

```
$(function(toggle_list){
$("#lists").on('click','a', function() {
    return !($(this).parents("li:first").find("ul:first").slideToggle('fast'))
});
});
```

Any takes?

Comment: have your tried dumping your `$.get` results using `console.log(result)` to see whether your results are returning as you expect?

Comment: Yup. My `jSON` is valid and it returns the result as expected. I even `console.log(buffer)` and it works as expected. But the problem lies to how should I nest the `<li>` inside `<ul>`, like this `<ul id=lists><li>result1<ul><li>result1.2</li></ul></li></ul>`

Comment: did you try `$('#lists').append(buffer);`?

Comment: @Snowburnt `append` did the job! How did I miss that. How do I assign this append only to the button that is clicked? I tried using `$(this)` but somehow it lies inside the `$.get` method.

Comment: @rolodex did you try declaring buffer inside the tree_click function? Also, start off the click handler with function(e), e is the click event.  use $(e.target) to get the button jquery object

Comment: @rolodex do you have a demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
$('ul#lists').on('click','.c',function(){
```

to:

```
$('ul#lists').on('click','.c',function(e){
```

specify var buffer inside this function but before the $.get call.

To append to the clicked UL, go like this inside the click handler:

```
$(e.target).append(buffer);
```

Comment: Thanks! I used `$(e.target).parent().append(buffer)`. Works gracefully, but now, my list toggler isn't working!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the click event is called and the ajax request is successful and it is returning an array, there is a problem with `var item = val[i];` because `val` itself is the current item in the array.

```
$(function (tree_click) {
    $('#lists').on('click', '.c', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('c'); //To assign this event once

        $.get('scripts/list.json', function (result, status) {
            var buffer = $.map(result, function (item) {
                return "<li><a href='#' cmd='" + item.command + "'>" + item.name + "</a></li>";
            }).join('');
            $('#lists').html(buffer);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This will result for only ONE object in the array.

Comment: I've updated my question with the JSON. I want to print the sample json nested into a new `ul` inside `ul#lists` so the parent can have more children.

Comment: "so the parent can have more children"...It's funny to read that after 4 years.